problemas con imagen en dompdf
Cuando intento generar un pdf con el dompdf me lo genera bien sin problemas, pero en ese mismo pdf necesito que coloque la imagen cuya direccion esta en la base de datos y la imagen en unba carpeta del servidor, es decir me muestre la imagen correspondiente a ese producto... ya he modificado el codigo de diferentes formas pero me sale el cuadro en blanco y no me muestra la imagen... si alguien me puede ayudar con eso se lo agradeceria.
dejo el codigo completo
<?php 
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php'; // Incluye la biblioteca DomPDF
require_once "../config/conexion.php";
$id = $_GET['pedidoId'];
$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE id = $id");
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$productos = json_decode($result['productos'], true);
$total_general = 0; // Inicializar el total general
$html = '

<html>
<body>


    <h1 style="text-align:center;"></h1>
    
    

<h3 style="text-align:right;">Orden Nro. 00-' . $result["id"] . '</h3>
<h4 style="text-align:right;">Fecha/Hora. ' . $result["fecha"] . '</h4>

<h4 style="text-align:left;">Nombre: ' . $result["nombre"] . '</h4>
<h4 style="text-align:left;">Correo: ' . $result["correo"] . '</h4>
<h4 style="text-align:left;">Telefono: ' . $result["telefono"] . '</h4>
<h4 style="text-align:left;">Tipo de entrega: ' . $result["tipoentrega"] . '</h4>
<h4 style="text-align:left;">Dirección: ' . $result["direccionentrega"] . '</h4>
        

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Imagen</th>
                <th>Codigo</th>
                <th>Producto</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>SubTotal</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';

foreach ($productos as $producto) {
$subtotal = $producto['cantidad'] * $producto['precio'];
$total_general += $subtotal; // Sumar al total general
$html .= '<tr>';
$html .= '<td>' . $producto['imagen'] . '</td>';
$html .= '<td>' . $producto['codigo'] . '</td>';
$html .= '<td>' . $producto['nombre'] . '</td>';
$html .= '<td style="text-align:center;">' . number_format($producto['precio'], 2) . '</td>';
$html .= '<td style="text-align:center;">' . $producto['cantidad'] . '</td>';
$html .= '<td style="text-align:center;">' . number_format($subtotal, 2) . '</td>';
$html .= '</tr>';
}

$html .= '
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" style="text-align:right;"><strong>Total General:</strong></td>
            <td style="text-align:center;">' . number_format($total_general, 2) . '</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>';

// Crea una instancia de Dompdf
$dompdf = new Dompdf();

// Carga el HTML en Dompdf
 $dompdf->loadHtml($html, 'UTF-8');

 // Renderiza el PDF
 $dompdf->render();


// Guarda el PDF en el servidor
$dompdf->stream($id.'-orden.pdf',array('Attachment' => 0));


Y como quieres mostrar la imagen sin un elemento que la muestre como tal ? necesitas ponerla dentro de un img o algo.
